# Is it possible to get a javascript console in vscode where I can see the editor's internal Javascript objects live?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Looks like most of the editor is implemented in Javascript.

Is there a plugin or similar which provides live console access to the editor's internal engine, so I can view/modify javascript objects live like in the console of a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the menu option: **Help** > **Toggle Developer Tools**